# Matrix transformation that "rotates" a matrix by $45^\circ$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, matrices

I have an $n \times n$ integer matrix $A$. I want to obtain an $m \times m$ matrix $B$, where $m \ge n$, such that the rows of $A$ are the diagonals of $B$ and the columns of $A$ are the anti-diagonals of $B$. Equivalently, $B$ is the result of "rotating" matrix $A$ a total of $45^\circ$ clockwise.

For example, the image of

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1& 2 & 3\\
4& 5 & 6 \\
7& 8& 9
\end{array}
\right)$$

is the following

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0& 0& 1 & 0 &0 \\
0& 4& 0& 2 &0 \\
7& 0& 5& 0& 3   \\
0 & 8& 0& 6 & 0 \\
0& 0& 9& 0& 0
\end{array}
\right)$$

My questions:

1. Has anyone studied the properties of such transformation?
2. Which algebraic operation does achieve such transformation?
3. Is there any interesting group-theoretic uses of such transformation?

Comment: Notice that since $B$ in general will have rank $m-1=2n-2$, larger than the typical rank of $A$, which is $n$, you cannot generally find matrices $C$ and $D$ such that $CAD=B$; and then clearly never  with $C$ and $D$ independent of $A$. So you are looking at just a linear embedding of ${\mathbb F}^{n\times n} \rightarrow {\mathbb F}^{m\times m}$ without immediately obvious further algebraic properties.

Comment: You should first extend the matrix $A$ to a matrix $A'$ of size $m$ and attach to each element $a'_{i,j}$ a point $P=P(i,j)$ of coordinates $(x,y)$ in the plane, rotate those points to get $P'(i,j)$ of coordinates $(x',y')$ and get $(k,l)=P^{-1}(x',y')$.

Comment: Note that the transposition of $A'$ corresponds to the map $(i,j)\mapsto(m+1-i,j)$ in its image. This corresponds to an automorphism of the diedral group with $8$ elements.

Comment: Ad 3: I think straightforward group theoretic implications are rather unlikely already since your transformation does not preserve invertibility of a matrix. That said, of course a definitive negative answer to the question as stated cannot be given.

Answer (score 2):

A way to rotate a 2D array by 45$^\circ$ by means of a [shear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) is worked out in [this Stack Overvlow posting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13546843)

[image]

The 45$^\circ$ shear mapping transforms a diagonal in the original array (black points) into a vertical column of the sheared array (red).

Comment: According to the linked Wikipedia article, the shear map fixes one coordinate (depending on whether the shear is parallel to the x-axis or the y-axis )  which is not the case in my example.